# Javascript issue - Space requied after public identifier

Tags: xml, web-services, parsing, hana

I am trying to write a javascript to send an XML to an external webservice which then processes it and sends an XML back. I am new to this and have made some mistake in this code which in turn gives the following error on output.
[image: Error screenshot]

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 50: Space required after the Public Identifier
>
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

The code is-

```
var dest = $.net.http.readDestination("Path","AddrService"));
var client = new $.net.http.Client();
var req = new $.net.http.Request( $.net.http.GET, "service/1services/addr");
var data = + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
+ '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">'
+ '<soapenv:Header/>'
+ '<soapenv:Body>'
   + '<urn:_-SIE_-ADDR_WS>'
      + '<IH_REQUESTER>9001</IH_REQUESTER>'
          
      + '<IF_ADDR_DIRECT>X</IF_ADDR_DIRECT>'
      + '<IT_ADDR_DIRECT>'
         + '<item>'
            + '<CONTROLLER>'
               + '<item>'
                  + '<FIELD/>'
                  + '<VALUE/>'
               + '</item>'
            + '</CONTROLLER>'
            + '<RECORD_ID>1</RECORD_ID>'
            + '<ORGANIZATION/>'
            + '<ADDRESS_LINE1>Hauptstrasse 6</ADDRESS_LINE1>'
            + '<ADDRESS_LINE2/>'
            + '<ADDRESS_LINE3/>'
            + '<ADDRESS_LINE4/>'
            + '<ADDRESS_LINE5/>'
            + '<ADDRESS_LINE6/>'
            + '<ADDRESS_LINE7/>'
            + '<ADDRESS_LINE8/>'
            + '<DOUBLE_DEPENDENT_LOCALITY/>'
            + '<DEPENDENT_LOCALITY/>'
            + '<LOCALITY>Zurich</LOCALITY>'
            + '<SUB_ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA/>'
            + '<ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA/>'
            + '<POSTAL_CODE>8090</POSTAL_CODE>'
            + '<SUB_NATIONAL_AREA/>'
            + '<COUNTRY>CH</COUNTRY>'
            + '<RECORD_OPTIONS/>'
         + '</item>'
      + '</IT_ADDR_DIRECT>'
   
    
   + '</urn:_-SIE_-ADDR_WS>'
+ '</soapenv:Body>'
+ '</soapenv:Envelope>' ;

try{
         
            var response = client.getResponse();
            response.contentType = "text/xml";
            req.setBody(data);
            client.request(req, dest);          
            var resBody = response.body.asString();
            $.response.status = $.net.http.OK; 
            $.response.setBody(resBody); 
           
}catch(errObj){
    $.response.setBody(errObj.message);
}
```

I have raised the question on the below link as well which explains my progress throughout this code. It also contains the XML which I am trying to send as a separate attachment.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 1):

```
var dest = $.net.http.readDestination("Path","AddrService"));
```

Try to remove this the double '))'

```
var dest = $.net.http.readDestination("Path","AddrService");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by html being sent in the request. Inspect the request you're sending to the server closely and you'll likely find something resembling the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"
```

Comment: What I've posted here is the entire code. There's no such mention of the statement you have posted as you can see in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the `+` just after `var data = + '...`

Comment: Yeah... doesn't help.